# Більш літературна форма "якщо що,...", чи існує вона?

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів, from-english

Аналог англійського "If anything,...". Можливо є кращий та красивіший аналог?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На практиці вживається «раптом що»:

- > Та ти не бійся. Зброї тут ні в кого немає, а **раптом що**, клич медсестру — вона тебе порятує. Сяйнувши глузливим усміхом, жартівник нарешті зник за дверима. // Марина Соколян, «Новендіалія» (Київ, «Факт», 2008)

Хоча це насправді є скороченням від того самого:

- укр. — «коли/як/якщо раптом що»;
- рос. — «если/коли/коли вдруг что».

Також сполучник можна пропустити, вставивши дієслово: «щось станеться — зателефонуй мені» (чомусь мені це видається неявним [кондиціоналісом](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%81), хоча, може, це й некоректна аналогія).

Також [«бодай»](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=47151&page=1488) і його часткові синоніми «хоч [би]», «[не]хай» уживаються не лише при побажаннях, а й у допустово-обмежувальному значенні, тож я припускаю, що теоретично можна було б сказати «бодай що — телефонуй мені», але в [літературі](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/) таких ужитків не знайшов.